# How is a Git branch different from a SVN branch?

Tags: git, svn, migration, branch

I'm about to migrate from SVN to Git.

All the articles I read about migration talks about how using Git over SVN means branching all the time.

What I don't get is how Git branches differ from SVN branches. How are they different?

Comment: In Subversion, a "branch" is just a copy of an arbitrary (sub)directory. In Git you can only create branches of the complete repository. Branches in Git are just "labels" to certain commits in Git's commit graph. Subversion doesn't have the same notion of a commit graph.

Comment: I can suggest the [Basic Branching and Merging](http://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging) chapter of the progit book for an introduction.

Comment: I know how branches work in GIT. I'm just not sure how they are different from branches in SVN.

Comment: @godmoney: In what respect different? How they are represented in the file system? What commands they accept? You have to be a little more specific

Comment: I want to know why in GIT it is recommended to make a new branch for each new feature but in SVN it doesn't work like this

Comment: Because branches in Git are lightweight and only exist in your local repository (until you push them elsewhere). Branches in Subversion must always be created on the central Subversion server for everybody to see. And you cannot really delete Subversion branches, they will stay forever on the server (with all their associated revisions). With Git, if you decide that you didn't need the branch in the first place, you can simply delete it. Nobody will ever know it existed.

Answer (score 0):

I think the main difference is this:

In git (and all other distributed version control (DVCS) systems), every developer always implicitly has their own branch at all times, therefore merges are easy because the system would not be usable if merges were hard. In DVCSes, merges are obvious in the history because they have multiple parent changesets.

In SVN, everyone has exactly the same project tree, you only get a branch if you explicitly ask for one. Merges are hard in SVN. Automatic merges were not even supported at all for a long time and they got tacked on later using a special "svn:mergeinfo" property which can be modified by the user, screwing everything up. Merges don't really show up in the history at all, unless you read this special property and manually reconstruct what happened.

You've been using SVN, so you've been trained that "merges are hard, therefore branches are bad". You need to forget all your SVN training. DVCS is different. Merges are your friend. Branches happen every time you commit; because there is not necessarily a central server, any number of people may have committed any number of changesets with the same parent, and all of these must eventually be merged** together.

This tutorial is for Mercurial (another DVCS), but the concepts also apply to git. It covers the concepts pretty well, and is designed for people coming from SVN: http://hginit.com

**In git specifically, people will often *rebase* rather than merge, but it's the same basic idea, and not every team encourages that.

Comment: Why in SVN merges are hard and in GIT they are not?

Comment: I probably should have said, "can be" rather than "are". But they certainly are usually *harder* than in Git or Mercurial. I think it has to do with the underlying concept of how each system tracks your changes. SVN tracks a big directory tree as it changes in time. Branches are just a convention. Any copy/branch has a history going back to find its parent, but does not have a very good way to track merges going forward. Git and similar systems instead track a collection of changesets and their relationships, including merges. The system always knows exactly where each change came from.

Comment: One more reason, mentioned at that hginit site I linked to, is the separation between the "commit" of a change, and pushing that change to others ("commit vs. "inflict") that exists in DVCS. When you work in SVN, you are encouraged by the system to wait until everything works before you commit anything. If you don't then you will often "break the build" for everybody else. In distributed systems, you can commit anything you want whenever you want, because it only affects YOUR repository. Smaller commits lead to easier merges.